# Creating a smooth installer for a C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, outlook-addin

I've checked the SO but didn't quite find the answer I'm looking for. I've created an add-in and I'm trying to create an installer using VS10, the *Publish* option. It works sort-of like supposed to but not fully. I've recognized four areas that I'd like to get more clarity on.

1. Making the set up process (more) quiet and, preferably, unsupervised.
2. Including packages not includable by the default publisher.
3. Error during the installation due to not trusted manifest.
4. Including only the necessary files and packages.

---

**1. Making the set up process (more) quiet and, preferably, unsupervised.**

Right now, the installer goes package-by-package and asks the user at five different occasions if the installation of such-and-such package is accepted and if the conditions are accepted. How can I make the installation quiet (and preferably fully unsupervised) so that the user only needs to double click on a setup file and, maybe, only answer OK once?

**2. Including packages not includable by the default publisher.**

One of the packages (WIF) is not listed in the list of includables but is still needed for the add-in to run. As of now, I need to ask the end user to manually install WIF **before** the rest of the installation (that's troublesome already, as described in the previous item) can continue. How can I package it all together?

**3. Error during the installation due to not trusted manifest.**

I'm getting errors during the installation complaining that the zone *Computer* doesn't trust my add-on. It's something like: "*System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for OutlookAddIn1 or its location is not trusted.*" in *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustPromptKeyInternal* and I have no idea how to handle it. Any suggestions?

**4. Including only the necessary files and packages.**

I'm not entirely sure how to check what packages that are necessary to include in order to guarantee my application to run. I can do it by trial-and-error or guess that the DLLs that are referenced are all that's needed but can i really trust that? I prefer not to get a morning surprise after I've sent the files to the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're run into bigger problems than so but, just in case you got lazy and hasn't checked with Google, there's an installer project inside Visual Studio 2010. I've only used it once, long time ago and under supervision so I'm not going to preach about it but here are the links to a walk-through.

1. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/07/12/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-1-of-2.aspx) is how you set up an add-in.
2. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/07/12/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-2-of-2.aspx) is how you set up an installation project.

Comment: Yes, while waiting on a reply I've found that too. The problem is that while the installation proceeds without errors, I get an exception when attempting to start up Outlook. Apparently the `VSTO` file can't be found... But that's subject for another question. Maybe you can give it a try and follow the steps? Who knows, perhaps you'll get into the same issues as I do...